# PutDatabaseRecort NumberFormatException: For input string 'yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s.S'

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have two similar `PutDatabaseRecords` processors which write to two tables on `Postgres DB` respectively: `src.sales` and `src.task_data`.

One of them writes the data successfully, but another fails with the error:

```
 2021-07-19 01:56:24,316 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.standard.PutDatabaseRecord PutDatabaseRecord[id=325364c0-0064-3127-92f0-6c1b83b076aa] Failed to put Records to database for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=a2265064-29fc-4472-832d-b3f8edf5f826,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1626647841973-1, container=default, section=1], offset=11792, length=1995],offset=0,name=3f1d0a15-dc53-4177-917b-e07d55ce6437,size=1995]. Routing to failure.: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2021-06-30 00:00:00.0"
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2021-06-30 00:00:00.0"
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
  at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.toDouble(DataTypeUtils.java:1402)
  at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:196)
  at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:153)
  at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:149)
  at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.executeDML(PutDatabaseRecord.java:709)
  at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.putToDatabase(PutDatabaseRecord.java:841)
  at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.onTrigger(PutDatabaseRecord.java:487)
  at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1173)
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:214)
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
  at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 2021-07-19 01:56:24,475 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@4f899a03 // Another save pending = false
```

I want to say again, that all configuration the same, except name of tables, fields etc.

This is a configuration of the processor:

[image: PutDatabaseRecord top]

[image: PutDatabaseRecord bottom]

This is configuration of reader:

[image: Reader top]

[image: Reader bottom]

This is the schema of `src.sales`, that is working:

```
{
    "name": "sales",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "maxi",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "nmcl_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "assort_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "rtt_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "rep_date",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "out_items",
        "type": "float"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is the schema of `src.task_data` that isn't working:

```
{
    "name": "task_data",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "maxi",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "doc_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "line_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "nmcl_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "assortment_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "org_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "items_qnt",
        "type": "float"
      },
      {
        "name": "start_date",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "end_date",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Sales table:

```
CREATE TABLE src.sales (
    nmcl_id int NOT NULL,
    assort_id int NOT NULL,
    rtt_id int NOT NULL,
    rep_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    out_items float NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY src.sales
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_sales PRIMARY KEY (nmcl_id, assort_id, rtt_id, rep_date);
```

Tasks table:

```
CREATE TABLE src.task_data (
    doc_id int not null,
    line_id int not null,
    nmcl_id int NOT NULL,
    assortment_id int NOT NULL,
    org_id int NOT NULL,
    start_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    end_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    items_qnt float NOT NULL,
    load_date timestamp NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY src.task_data
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_task_data PRIMARY KEY (doc_id, line_id);
```

Sales `JSON`:

```
[{"rep_date": "2021-06-25 00:00:00.0", "nmcl_id": "494031", "assort_id": "7", "rtt_id": "100", "out_items": "2"} ... ]
```

Tasks `JSON`:

```
[{"doc_id": "1797690451", "line_id": "691950586", "org_id": "5", "nmcl_id": "349589", "assortment_id": "7", "items_qnt": "1.67", "start_date": "2021-06-29 00:00:00.0", "end_date": "2021-06-30 00:00:00.0", "load_date": null} ... ]
```

Sales fetch schema:

```
02:21:05 MSK DEBUG
PutDatabaseRecord[id=ee811cfb-3db0-1d69-8c8a-772e960df75f] Fetched Table Schema TableSchema[columns=[
Column[name=nmcl_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10],
Column[name=assort_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10],
Column[name=rtt_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10],
Column[name=rep_date, dataType=93, required=true, columnSize=29],
Column[name=out_items, dataType=8, required=true, columnSize=17]]] for table name sales
```

Tasks fetch schema:

```
02:25:43 MSK DEBUG
PutDatabaseRecord[id=325364c0-0064-3127-92f0-6c1b83b076aa] Fetched Table Schema TableSchema[columns=[
Column[name=doc_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10],
Column[name=line_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10]
Column[name=nmcl_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10], Column[name=assortment_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10],
Column[name=org_id, dataType=4, required=true, columnSize=10],
Column[name=start_date, dataType=93, required=true, columnSize=29],
Column[name=end_date, dataType=93, required=true, columnSize=29],
Column[name=items_qnt, dataType=8, required=true, columnSize=17],
Column[name=load_date, dataType=93, required=false, columnSize=13]]] for table name task_data
```

I tried to put date format string in appropriate fields in the `JsonPathReader`'s config and I tried to make the date field: `type: "int", logicalType: "date"` in the schema.

I tried it in the same time and in different time... the result is the same.

So, what can be a difference? Where the problem is?

Comment: I'm reading this: `sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)` as the application thinking the input is supposed to be a `Float`. Are you sure the code you are modifying is the code that is actually running?

Comment: Yes! Your almost right! It not about the same code? it is about column order!!! The order of columns in schema must be the same as in DB!!! So because `start_date` became to the place of `items_qnt` it try to handle it as `float`.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian Klever said, the issue is around of a `float`!

I had this problem previously, but forgot about.

Here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200350/numberformatexception-for-unicode-string-in-nifi).